# Test for presence of specific text in tag with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm interested in testing for the presence of specific text (an error message) on pages that I'm scraping. I have the following working statement:

```
   not_found=response.selector.xpath('//*[@id="Error"]/font[contains(text(),"is not found")]')
```

I can see that their is a boolean test mentioned in the docs ([https://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.12/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.XPathSelector.**nonzero**](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.12/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.XPathSelector.__nonzero__)) but I'm not sure if I can apply it here to do something like (pseudocode):

```
    if __nonzero__(not_found):
```

I was having trouble finding it to import so have not been able to test properly. How can I get this working?

Comment: `if not_found:` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doc: [`__nonzero__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__)

It is used automatically when you do `bool(not_found)`
and `bool()` is use automatically when you do `if not_found:`

---

You don't have to use `__nonzero__` and you shouldn't use it directly (because you have `bool()` for this) but if you really have to then it should be `not_found.__nonzero__()`